# Unity Shader overriding Mesh UVs. How can I fix it?

Tags: unity-game-engine, textures, shader, mesh, terrain

I have a terrain made out of four meshes. To these meshes I have added one single texture and created the individual UV maps for each of the meshes. All pretty and done, but when I try to apply a shader :

```
 Shader.Find( "Transparent/Bumped Diffuse" );
```

, it creates a good texture for one of the meshes that repeats itself over the others. How can I fix this or how can I activate the transparency of the texture through code otherwise?

Here is the code:

```
             for (int i=0; i<4; i++) {

                    myWaterMesh[i]  = new Mesh();
            myWater[i]      = new GameObject();
            myWater[i].name = "Water";

            myWater[i].AddComponent<MeshFilter>  ().mesh = myWaterMesh[i];
            myWater[i].AddComponent<MeshRenderer>();

            myWaterMesh[i].vertices  = verticesWater[i];
            myWaterMesh[i].triangles = triangles;
            myWaterMesh[i].uv        = uv[i];
            myWaterMesh[i].RecalculateNormals();

            //Apply texture and transparent shader
            myWater[i].renderer.material.mainTexture = waterMap;

            Shader myShader = Shader.Find( "Transparent/Bumped Diffuse" );

            myWater[i].renderer.material.shader = myShader;

        }
```

Comment: I'm not sure if I get you right here, but have applied a different material to every mesh?

Comment: @Wipster I have added the code. If i comment out the Shader bit, it applies the texture correctly over four meshes, but the transparency is lost. If I use the shader, one Mesh uv map repeats itself over the others.

Comment: Hmm, could you try this: myWater[i].renderer.material = new Material(Shader.Find("Transparent/Bumped Diffuse"));

Comment: @Wipster Strangely, it turns the mesh to white. If i put the line before I apply the texture, it turns it to black. I will probably generate four separate textures from the main one.